# What is the best way to use two pole DC power supplies to power op-amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc

Apologies, I think this is a very basic question, and it may be that there is already an answer, but when I searched I did not find it exactly.

What is the best way to use two pole DC power supplies to power op-amps which it seems to me may need 3 voltage rails of 0 and +/- *N* V - where *N* may be 5, 12 etc.

So most DC power supplies supply 0, +12 V or similar, but op-amps normally need say 0 V and +/-5 V, three input lines. - Or at least it needs the +/- 5 V say plus the signal needs to come in at 0V so I am guessing I need a 0V rail...

So I could use a voltage divider to make +6V from the 0 and +12 and then have 0, +6 and +12 V lines, but I expect that would be really inefficient.

I am guessing that there is a standard way to do this. Any suggestions?

Oh and I looked at [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231195/powering-op-amp-current) and [this question, which suggests voltage regulators](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider)

Comment: The most general solution is to use a regulator to generate the additional voltages, but this isn't always necessary.  Often you can get away with supplying an opamp with just two voltages (e.g. 0 and 5V), especially if the input voltage you want to amplify and the output voltage you want to generate are both somewhere in between those two voltages.  It would help to define your specific problem and from there you can work on which solution makes sense.

Comment: thanks @user1850479, just seeing your comment now. I was wondering about a couple to different applications, like a guitar amplifier or an amplifier that works at higher frequencies for small signals- maybe even about 10 MHz. This was also a fundamental question in my head wondering about how, for example, a radio with a battery works, as it must have amplifiers, but only has a two pole power supply, and you don't want to waste battery power....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a lot of cases a voltage divider with bypass capacitors to create a 'virtual ground' will work fine, especially if you only need it for a couple of opamps.

In other cases a resistive divider will not be able to supply enough current so you'll need a rail splitter, this can be done by following the divider with an opamp something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ZO95.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Even more current can be had by adding a complementary transistor buffer after the opamp, or by following the divider with something like a [BUF634](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/buf634.pdf) buffer.

Another option is a voltage converter IC such as the [ADM660](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM660_8660.pdf). This can be a good option if you want to increase the voltage available, as it will create a negative voltage equal to the positive supply (within limits) rather than splitting the positive supply in half, so it will take a +5 V supply and give you +/-5 V rather than the +/-2.5 V a splitter would.

Or you could go with single supply operation, [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa030a/sloa030a.pdf) is some information on that.

Comment: Many thanks. I really appreciate your answer, that all makes sense to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is meant as sort of an addition to the above answer.

Op amps don't know or care about what you've arbitrarily labeled the inputs powering it as. There is no difference between ±5V and 0V and 10V. All that matters is the voltage difference between the power terminals of the op amp and what the output voltage is referred to (which is what virtual grounds are used for).

This means you can just as readily power a ±6V op amp from 0V and 12V rails. And in fact, both cases are identical. Only your labels for the voltage rails have changed, but it is the same circuit either way.

The op amp's output will swing between these two rails, so if you have labeled your rails ±6V, then whe the offset voltage is seen at the + and - terminals of the op amp, you'll get 0V (according to how you've labeled things) out.

If instead you have labeled the voltages 0V and 12V, you'll get 6V out. But again, in both cases, the circuit is identical, we are only changing how we choose to label our voltages. It is ultimately arbitrary. We could just as readily label it -108V and -120V if we wanted.

Of course, we use these labels to drive how we design the circuit. In the case of ±6V, this has the implication you have a rail half way between the positive and negative rails that you've chosen to be your 0V reference. But it is not actually required. The op amp doesn't need a 0V, it doesn't know what that is. It just needs voltage difference of the right polarity across its two power terminals, and as long as the input voltage across the inverting and noninverting terminals is within acceptable limits of the power rails (usually further than a volt or so, but it depends on the op amp), that is all that matters. The output voltage will be referred to the input voltage. You can label those voltages whatever you want (as long as you have the relative difference correct in polarity and magnitude), but it is left up to the designer to derive, say, '0V' if they need it. And it need not be in the middle, it could be 2V above the negative rail or anywhere in between, and depending on what output voltage swing you need, this might be perfectly acceptable. Symmetric power rails are really only needed when amplifying bipolar or AC signals.

In the case of ±6V, this is the same as having a 0V, 6V, and 12V rail.

There is one little gotchya however, which is when using voltage regulators (and the reason there are positive and negative voltage regulators). It has to do with the direction of current - sourcing it or sinking it. Positive regulators generally can only source current, and negative ones can only sink current. Being able to do both (bidirectional current flow) requires a push-pull output. There are regulators that can work in either role, but they are uncommon. However, op-amps have push pull outputs, so in reality, virtual-ground circuits are really just discrete voltage regulators that are capable of bidirectional current flow, and we use this to drive the op amp inputs and set what the output will be referred/relative to.

Comment: many thanks for the extra information, I appreciate it